# Avoid typescript casting inside a switch

Tags: typescript, casting, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Consider the following code:

```
interface FooBarTypeMap {
  FOO: FooInterface;
  BAR: BarInterface;
}

type FooBarTypes = "FOO" | "BAR";

export interface FooBarAction<T extends FooBarTypes> {
  type: T;
  data: FooBarTypeMap[T];
}

const doSomthingBasedOnType = (action: FooBarAction<FooBarTypes>): void => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FOO":
      FooAction((action as FooBarAction<"FOO">));
  }
};

const FooAction = (action: FooBarAction<"FOO">): void => {
  //do something with action.data
};
```

Now I would like to avoid the casting (action as FooBarAction<"FOO">) as seen in doSomthingBasedOnType, as the very definition if the interface makes this the only possibility inside this switch. Is there something I can change in my code for this to work, or is this simply a bug in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform `FooBarAction` into a discriminated union. At  the moment your version of `FooBarAction` is not very strict, while `type` must be one of `"FOO" | "BAR"` and `data` must be one of `FooBarTypeMap[FooBarTypes] = FooInterface | BarInterface` there is no relation between the two. So this could be allowed:

```
let o : FooBarAction2<FooBarTypes> = {
  type: "BAR",
  data: {} as FooInterface
}
```

The discriminated union version would look like this:

```
export type FooBarAction = {
  type: "FOO";
  data: FooInterface;
} | {
  type: "BAR";
  data: BarInterface;
}

const doSomthingBasedOnType = (action: FooBarAction): void => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FOO":
      FooAction(action);
  }
};

// We use extract to get a specific type from the union
const FooAction = (action: Extract<FooBarAction, { type: "FOO" }>): void => {
  //do something with action.data
};
```

You can also create a union from a union of types using the distributive behavior of conditional types:

```
interface FooInterface { foo: number}
interface BarInterface { bar: number}
interface FooBarTypeMap {
  FOO: FooInterface;
  BAR: BarInterface;
}

type FooBarTypes = "FOO" | "BAR";

export type FooBarAction<T extends FooBarTypes> = T extends any ? {
  type: T;
  data: FooBarTypeMap[T];
}: never;


const doSomthingBasedOnType = (action: FooBarAction<FooBarTypes>): void => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FOO":
      FooAction(action);
  }
};

const FooAction = (action: FooBarAction<"FOO">): void => {
  //do something with action.data
};
```

Comment: Seems to be working, but could you explain this part:
    T extends any ? {
      type: T;
      data: FooBarTypeMap[T];
    }: never;

Comment: @MrMamen This is called "Distributive conditional types" you can read more about it here:   https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: I've expanded the interfaces to include their own type. Using this I was hoping I could generate a (generic) FooBarAction, but I'm struggeling with typings.
`interface FooInterface { foo: number, type: "FOO"}
interface BarInterface { bar: number, type: "BAR"}
const createFooBarAction = (fooBarData: FooBarTypeMap[FooBarTypes]): FooBarAction<FooBarTypes> => ({
  type: fooBarData.type,
  data: fooBarData
})`

Comment: @MrMamen could you please post it as a new question with the full code ? I can't answer right now maybe someone else will and the comments are a really bad place to put a lot of code :)

Comment: Good point, created one here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428841/creating-a-discriminated-union-for-a-typescript-function